# Is it possible to return a custom column value from the sql database table using slick?

Tags: scala, slick-3.0, slick-2.0

There is a scenario when the requestType="HR" (which comes from the HTTP PUT request), it should return all the students information but return title as "EMPLOYEE"

For example, consider a "student" table with columns name,id, and title

```
 +-------+----+--------------------+
 + name  | id | title              +            
 +-------+----+--------------------+
 | KING  | 10 | SOFTWARE ENGINEER  |
 | BLAKE | 30 | SYSTEMS  ENGINEER  |
 +-------+----+--------------------+
```

**GOAL**: return all students, and override title="EMPLOYEE"

Here is what I have so far

```
 case class Student(name: String, id: Long, title: String)

 class StudentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Student](tag, "student") {
      def name = column[String]("name")
      def id = column[Long]("id")
      def title = column[String]("title")
      override def * = (name, id, title) <> ((Student.tupled, Student.unapply)
 }

 lazy val studentsQuery = TableQuery[StudentTable]
```

When i try to map and change the **title** value in the query, it complains about "re-assignment to val"

```
 val f = studentsQuery.map(p => p.title = "EMPLOYEE).result
```

> complier error: Reassignment to val

**Approach 2:**
I tried to pass in the requestType as a function parameter to the StudentTable, so that I can modify the title value based on the requestType. But then was not able to define studentsQuery since it was complaining about the "required tag".

```
 class StudentTable(tag: Tag)(reqType: String) extends Table[Student](tag, "student") {
      def name = column[String]("name")
      def id = column[Long]("id")
      def title = req.type match {
           case "HR" => "EMPLOYEE"
           case _ => column[String]("title")
      }
      override def * = (name, id, title) <> ((Student.tupled, Student.unapply)
 }

 // Didn't understand how to provide tag 
 lazy val studentsQuery = TableQuery[StudentTable]()("HR")
```

> compilation error: unspecified value parameters: Cons: (Tag) => StudentTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to do it from Slick, but found a way to do it using json serialization.

```
 import scala.concurrent.Await
 import scala.concurrent.duration._
 import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

 case class Student(name: String, id: Long, title: String)

 class StudentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Student](tag, "student") {
      def name = column[String]("name")
      def id = column[Long]("id")
      def title = column[String]("title")
      override def * = (name, id, title) <> ((Student.tupled,Student.unapply)}

 lazy val studentsQuery = TableQuery[StudentTable]


 implicit def StudentDataWrites = new Writes[Student] {
     def writes(student: Student) =
          Json.obj(
              "name"  -> student.name,
              "id"    -> student.id,
              "title" -> "EMPLOYEE"
            )
 }

 def getStudentsInfo() = Action {
    val students= Await.Result(db.run(studentsQuery.size.result), 10.seconds) 
    Ok(Json.obj("students" -> Json.toJson(students)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
val f = studentsQuery.map(p => p.title = "EMPLOYEE).result
```

you should have:

```
val f = studentsQuery.result.map(_.map(p => p.copy(title = "EMPLOYEE")))
```

Comment: Hello Pawel 

Cannot get your code to execute 

Compiler complaining about 2 things:
1. Cannot resolve reference copy with such signature 
2. Cannot resolve symbol title

Comment: Which version of Slick are you using? You've provided contradictory tags (`slick-2.0` and `slick-3.0`), so it's not clear which one you have.

Comment: Im using slick2.0